# Kubernetes CoreDNS pods are endlessly restarting

Tags: kubernetes, centos7

I'm working on installing a three node kubernetes cluster on a CentOS 7 with flannel for a some time, however the CoreDNS pods cannot connect to API server and constantly restarting.

The reference HowTo document I followed is [here](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/centos-kubernetes-docker-cluster/).

### What Have I Done so Far?

- Disabled SELinux,
- Disabled `firewalld`,
- Enabled `br_netfilter`, `bridge-nf-call-iptables`,
- Installed kubernetes on three nodes, set-up master's pod network with flannel default network (`10.244.0.0/16`),
- Installed other two nodes, and joined the master.
- Deployed flannel,
- Configured Docker's BIP to use flannel default per-node subnet and network.

### Current State

- The kubelet works and the cluster reports nodes as ready.
- The Cluster can schedule and migrate pods, so CoreDNS are spawned on nodes.
- Flannel network is connected. No logs in containers and I can ping `10.244.0.0/24` networks from node to node.
- Kubernetes can deploy and run arbitrary pods (Tried [shell demo](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/get-shell-running-container/), and can access its shell via `kubectl` even if the container is on a different node.

  - However, since DNS is not working, they cannot resolve any IP addresses.

### What is the Problem?

- CoreDNS pods report that they cannot connect to API server with error:

  ```
    Failed to list *v1.Namespace: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: connect: no route to host
  ```
- I cannot see `10.96.0.0` routes in routing tables:

  ```
    default via 172.16.0.1 dev eth0 proto static metric 100 
    10.1.0.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.1.0.202 metric 101 
    10.244.0.0/24 via 10.244.0.0 dev flannel.1 onlink 
    10.244.1.0/24 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 10.244.1.1 
    10.244.1.0/24 dev cni0 proto kernel scope link src 10.244.1.1 
    10.244.2.0/24 via 10.244.2.0 dev flannel.1 onlink 
    172.16.0.0/16 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 172.16.0.202 metric 100
  ```

### Additional Info

- Cluster init is done with the command `kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address=172.16.0.201 --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16`.
- I have torn down the cluster and rebuilt with 1.12.0 The problem still persists.
- The workaround in Kubernetes [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/troubleshooting-kubeadm/#coredns-pods-have-crashloopbackoff-or-error-state) doesn't work.
- Problem is present and same both with `1.11-3`and `1.12-0` CentOS7 packages.

### Progress so Far

- Downgraded Kubernetes to `1.11.3-0`.
- Re-initialized Kubernetes with `kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address=172.16.0.201 --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16`, since the server has another external IP which cannot be accessed via other hosts, and Kubernetes tends to select that IP as API Server IP. `--pod-network-cidr` is mandated by [flannel](https://coreos.com/flannel/docs/latest/kubernetes.html).
- Resulting `iptables -L` output after initialization *with no joined nodes*

  ```
    Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
    target     prot opt source               destination         
    KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW /* kubernetes externally-visible service portals */
    KUBE-FIREWALL  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

    Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
    target     prot opt source               destination         
    KUBE-FORWARD  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* kubernetes forwarding rules */
    DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

    Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
    target     prot opt source               destination         
    KUBE-SERVICES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW /* kubernetes service portals */
    KUBE-FIREWALL  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

    Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
    target     prot opt source               destination         
    RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

    Chain KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES (1 references)
    target     prot opt source               destination         

    Chain KUBE-FIREWALL (2 references)
    target     prot opt source               destination         
    DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* kubernetes firewall for dropping marked packets */ mark match 0x8000/0x8000

    Chain KUBE-FORWARD (1 references)
    target     prot opt source               destination         
    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* kubernetes forwarding rules */ mark match 0x4000/0x4000

    Chain KUBE-SERVICES (1 references)
    target     prot opt source               destination         
    REJECT     udp  --  anywhere             10.96.0.10           /* kube-system/kube-dns:dns has no endpoints */ udp dpt:domain reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    REJECT     tcp  --  anywhere             10.96.0.10           /* kube-system/kube-dns:dns-tcp has no endpoints */ tcp dpt:domain reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
  ```
- Looks like API Server is deployed as it should

  ```
    $ kubectl get svc kubernetes -o=yaml
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: 2018-10-25T06:58:46Z
      labels:
        component: apiserver
        provider: kubernetes
      name: kubernetes
      namespace: default
      resourceVersion: "6"
      selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/services/kubernetes
      uid: 6b3e4099-d823-11e8-8264-a6f3f1f622f3
    spec:
      clusterIP: 10.96.0.1
      ports:
      - name: https
        port: 443
        protocol: TCP
        targetPort: 6443
      sessionAffinity: None
      type: ClusterIP
    status:
      loadBalancer: {}
  ```
- Then I've applied flannel network pod with

  ```
    kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
  ```
- As soon as I apply the flannel network, CoreDNS pods start and start to give the same error:

  ```
    Failed to list *v1.Endpoints: Get https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/endpoints?limit=500\u0026resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: connect: no route to host
  ```
- I've found out that `flanneld` is using the wrong network interface, and changed it in the `kube-flannel.yml` file before deployment. However the outcome is still the same.

Comment: what if you run kubeadm and let it decide the networks itself

Comment: AFAIK Flannel's network addresses are hard-coded. Then you have to configure flannel to fit to kubernetes. I'll try that next. Currently someone else is also working on it, so I cannot rebuild the cluster.

Comment: I suspect some network overlapping issues

Comment: try to test it on a test cluster/test enviroement

Comment: The servers are VMs dedicated to Kubernetes. Neither 10.244.0.0/16, nor 172.16.0.0/16 has collisions. Servers have no extra software.So it's a dedicated testing cluster.

Comment: if it is a testing cluster then just re-create it without subnet options

Comment: I don't know if your problem is related to this but there is a problem between k8s 1.12 version and flannel. You can read this:  https://github.com/coreos/flannel/issues/1044

Comment: @YavuzSert thanks for the heads up! Unfortunately, the problem is also present with version `1.11`. Nevertheless, I'll downgrade before trying again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved the problem. The cause is a mixture of inexperience, lack of documentation and some old, no-longer-correct information.

The guy who will be using the installation told me that Docker's bridge needs to be in the same subnet with the Flannel network, hence I edited Docker's bridge network.

However, when Kubernetes started to use CNI, this requirement not only became unnecessary, but plain wrong. Having both `cni0` and `docker0` on the same network with same IP address always felt wrong, but since I'm a complete beginner in Kubernetes, I ignored my hunch.

As a result, I reset Docker's network to its default, tore down the cluster and rebuilt it. Now everything is working as it should.

**TL;DR:** Never, ever touch Docker's network parameters if you are setting up a recent Kubernetes release. Just install Docker, init the Kubernetes and deploy Flannel. Kubernetes and CNI will take care of container to Flannel transport.

Answer (score 4):

This is basically saying that your coredns pod cannot talk to the kube-apiserver. The kube-apiserver is exposed in the pod through these environment variables: `KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST=10.96.0.1` and `KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT_HTTPS=443`

I believe that the routes that you posted are routes on the host since this is what you get when you run `ip routes` in pod container:

```
root@xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxx:/# ip route
default via 169.254.1.1 dev eth0
169.254.1.1 dev eth0  scope link
root@xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxx:/#
```

In any case, you wouldn't see `10.96.0.1` since that's exposed in the cluster using iptables. So what is that address? It happens that is a `service` in the default namespace called `kubernetes`. That service's `ClusterIP` is `10.96.0.1` and it's listening on port `443`, it also maps to `targetPort` `6443` which is where your kube-apiserver is running.

Since you can deploy pods, etc. It seems like the kube-apiserver is not down and that's not your problem. So most likely you are missing that service (or there's some iptable rule not allowing you to connect to it). You can see it here, for example:

```
$ kubectl get svc kubernetes
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP   92d
```

The full output is something like this:

```
$ kubectl get svc kubernetes -o=yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2018-07-23T21:10:22Z
  labels:
    component: apiserver
    provider: kubernetes
  name: kubernetes
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "24"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/services/kubernetes
  uid: xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.96.0.1
  ports:
  - name: https
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 6443
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

So if you are missing it, you can create it like this:

```
cat <<EOF
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    component: apiserver
    provider: kubernetes
  name: kubernetes
  namespace: default
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.96.0.1
  ports:
  - name: https
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 6443
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
EOF | kubectl apply -f -
```

Answer (score 1):

This steps fixed my problem:

```
systemctl stop kubelet
systemctl stop docker
iptables --flush
iptables -tnat --flush
systemctl start kubelet
systemctl start docker
```

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me.  VM CentOS 7.

Answer (score 0):

I met this before. The Firewalld had opened the port 6443 to my real LAN IPs, but it still disables others, so I tried to shut down the Firewall via the CMD :

```sh
systemctl stop firewalld
```

It works and all exceptions that coming from kubectl logs were gone, so the root cause is the firewall rules of your linux servers.